# Really easy question i am still learning how to do linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
class List {
private:
    Node* head = NULL; //makes it emty
    Node* tail = NULL; 
public:
    void insert(int entry) {
        Node* tmp = new Node; 
        tmp->data = entry;        
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) 
        {
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else 
        {
            tail->next = tmp; 
            tail = tail->next; 
        }
    }

    void printout() {
        while (head!= NULL) {
            cout << head->data; // counts the data
            head = head->next; // goes to the next node
        }
    }
    void replace(int pos, int entry) {
        Node* temp;
        temp = head;
        int count = pos;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (i == count) {
                temp->data = entry;
            }
            else {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I am sure i am missing something super easy but it keeps telling me this "Exception thrown: read access violation. temp was nullptr." i am confused on where to go from here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I also think the printout is the problem. You don't want to change head. Use a separate variable to iterate instead of head.

Comment: Like others above said, problem seems to be printout() method destroying your list because you are using global variable "head" directly. always copy it onto a "temphead" and use that. Also put your main() method and other lines of code making use of this class of "List" into your example

Comment: Ultimately, problem is, as @RemyLebeau mentioned in the first comment, you are not checking for Null value for "temp" variable. since tail->next is null which denotes the end of the list, you should check for it, Since "pos" value might indicate a position beyond the end of your list.

Comment: Code as written cannot produce the error you are getting since your example *does not run any of the code shown*.  You need to include the code that is actually running to generate the error, otherwise everything above is just speculation.  There are some obvious problems in your code, but the specific error you are getting is due to *how you are using the code*, which you have elided.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `"temp was nullptr"` seems very self-explanatory to me. There is only one `temp` in the code shown, that is in `replace()`. You are not validating that `temp` is not `NULL` before accessing its members.  In fact, `replace()` isn't looping correctly in general.  It doesn't stop looping when it reaches the desired `Node`, and it doesn't handle the cases when `pos` is outside the bounds of the list.

Also, your `printout()` method is destroying the list, since it is modifying the `head` member.  It should be using a non-destructive loop instead.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node(int value) : data(value) {}
};

class List {
private:
    Node* head = nullptr; //makes it emty
    Node* tail = nullptr; 

public:
    List() = default;

    ~List() {
        Node *tmp = head, *next;
        while (tmp) {
            next = tmp->next;
            delete tmp;
            tmp = next;
        }
    }

    // deleted until you are ready to implement them properly...
    List(const List&) = delete;
    List(List&&) = delete;
    List& operator=(const List&) = delete;
    List& operator=(List&&) = delete;
    //

    void insert(int entry) {
        Node* tmp = new Node{entry};
        if (!head)
            head = tmp;
        else 
            tail->next = tmp; 
        tail = tmp; 
    }

    void printout() const {
        Node *tmp = head;
        while (tmp) {
            cout << tmp->data; // counts the data
            tmp = tmp->next; // goes to the next node
        }
    }

    void replace(int pos, int entry) {
        if (pos < 0) return;
        Node* temp = head;
        while ((pos > 0) && (temp)) {
            temp = temp->next;
            --pos;
        }
        if (temp) {
            temp->data = entry;
        }
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/P6KxeT)